# Add row dynamically to AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I would like to add new row on the fly (runtime) to my AdvancedDataGrid.
I can add it to the data model, but couldn’t find a way to make the table render and show the new row.

What i am seeking for is to create an effect of expandable item, where clicking on row will show "additional information" (like a drawer) and clicking on row expand button will reveal it's children.

I saw examples of this for dataGrid ([http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_10.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439261/add-row-dynamically-to-advanceddatagrid)), but not for AdavancedDataGrid.

Only way I found to do this is to add a new child and use openItem, but this cause the other children to be visible as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If other rows are expanded do you want them to remain open after the new row is inserted as well? Is the default state of your rows expanded or collapsed?

Answer (score 1):

you need to revalidate the whole datagrid after you added a new item, so that all the new elements can become visible.

```
yourDataGrid.validateNow();
```

This should help:)